# issue parsing json from 3rd party server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I've got a Grease Monkey script that basically gathers information from a game and sends it to my server to keep track of progress for our team. This involves quite a few Ajax requests between my GM script and the game, and then sending one large dump to the server. During the data collection from the game, it seems one or more of the request results are improperly formatted JSON. I've printed it to console, and it seems to be a string rather than an object. I tried some quick `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(r))` but that throws an `unexpected end of data` error. After some research, I've come up with the function below to handle the Ajax response, but the logged "object" still appears to be a string, and still causes the rest of the script to fail.

```
function(r){
    if(typeof r === 'object'){
        result = r;
    }else if(typeof r === 'string'){
        r.trim();
        if(r.charAt(0) == '"'){
            fNQ = r.indexOf('"') + 1;
            lNQ = r.lastIndexOf('"');
            r = r.substring(fNQ, lNQ);
            r = r.trim();
        }
        uW.console.log(r);
        result = r;
    }   
    if(!result){
        result = r;
    }
}
```

How can I ensure that the 3rd party's Ajax response is properly formatted into JSON for use by the rest of the script?

EDIT - Below is the response that seems to trigger my errors:

```
" 







{"ok":true,"currentPage":1,"noOfPages":119,"otherAlliances":[{"allianceId":2090,"description":"Everyone has a Voice.  Everyone is Equal.  No Wild attacks other than that, treat other members with respect in chat, be active, nothing else but having fun your way!!!","membersCount":"77","name":"Rebels Forever","founderUserId":"18985927","might":"4003992566340","glory":"4439079","ranking":1,"hostUserId":"19002651","host":"Greywolf","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Greywolf","founderName":"GreywolfII","founderGenderAndName":"Lord GreywolfII"},{"allianceId":4428,"description":"When the world isnt what you thought.  Things are not what they seemed.  Phuck it take two of these mix with Alcohol and feel better in the morning.","membersCount":"92","name":"Phuckitol","founderUserId":"450033","might":"3070673000317","glory":"808848","ranking":2,"hostUserId":"450033","host":"Steelman","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Steelman","founderName":"Steelman","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Steelman"},{"allianceId":3253,"description":"Play as you like with the backing of your family. We fight as one and defend as one. Gem prizes will be handed out. Important to have fun and enjoy the game. Zilla","membersCount":"46","name":"Burn In Ashes","founderUserId":"3359434","might":"2596318711111","glory":"1914207","ranking":3,"hostUserId":"12858988","host":"gaz","hostGenderAndName":"Lord gaz","founderName":"Real'Savage","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Real'Savage"},{"allianceId":3262,"description":"Come join us and work as a team to fight and win :)","membersCount":"86","name":"Rise of Legends","founderUserId":"15149877","might":"2379467424780","glory":"2237089","ranking":4,"hostUserId":"15149877","host":"BRETT","hostGenderAndName":"Lord BRETT","founderName":"BRETT","founderGenderAndName":"Lord BRETT"},{"allianceId":3215,"description":":) zero drama tolerance, a place to fight and have fun. Is suppose to be a game after all","membersCount":"67","name":"trouble makers","founderUserId":"1887356","might":"2348999870474","glory":"2428809","ranking":5,"hostUserId":"11564038","host":"Dem0","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Dem0","founderName":"'Echo'","founderGenderAndName":"Lady 'Echo'"},{"allianceId":4924,"description":"","membersCount":"52","name":"WDW","founderUserId":"11577054","might":"2271325408341","glory":"2996503","ranking":6,"hostUserId":"11577054","host":"Nordic","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Nordic","founderName":"Nordic","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Nordic"},{"allianceId":2792,"description":"Name says it all :)","membersCount":"80","name":"Wicked MisFits","founderUserId":"18718109","might":"1984311364223","glory":"2303516","ranking":7,"hostUserId":"18718109","host":"Of_Sin","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Of_Sin","founderName":"Of_Sin","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Of_Sin"},{"allianceId":3881,"description":"","membersCount":"55","name":"LA  MEUTE","founderUserId":"14440588","might":"1807184812409","glory":"862782","ranking":8,"hostUserId":"15336296","host":"lepoison","hostGenderAndName":"Lord lepoison","founderName":"LouvePoison","founderGenderAndName":"Lady LouvePoison"},{"allianceId":3273,"description":"Italians do it better.","membersCount":"80","name":"MADE in ITALY","founderUserId":"18656989","might":"1799034994799","glory":"718309","ranking":9,"hostUserId":"19009341","host":"Super_Bicio","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Super_Bicio","founderName":"Leonida","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Leonida"},{"allianceId":5283,"description":"Fight and have fun!","membersCount":"26","name":"War  Crimes","founderUserId":"15105685","might":"1599775320583","glory":"6732908","ranking":10,"hostUserId":"15105685","host":"Hillz","hostGenderAndName":"Lady Hillz","founderName":"Hillz","founderGenderAndName":"Lady Hillz"}]}"
```

Comment: can you post an example response json?

Comment: @YasserElsayed updated the question with the json response in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to parse the string after stringifying it again. Remove that extra `JSON.stringify`, otherwise you'll end up with extra quotation marks.

Comment: You are correct that this was inhibiting the script. Upon further operation of the script with the debugging I now have in place, I found that one of the final responses that also causes the script to crash was actually a bit of code sent by the server : `" 

 





( function() { return eval(unescape("%76%61%72%20%73%20%3d%20%6e%65%77%20%44%61%74%65%28%29%3b%20%3b%20%64%6f%20%7b%20%3b%20%7d%20%77%68%69%6c%65%28%28%6e%65%77%20%44%61%74%65%28%29%29%20%2d%20%73%20%3c%20%32%30%31%38%29%3b")); })()"`

Comment: @chaoskreator that code seems to create a loop for 2018 milliseconds, for some reason.  It seems a bit odd that it is hidden behind an `unescape` *and* an `eval`.

Comment: @Jaketr00 Yeah I unescaped it all and saw the weird count and was wondering what it might be for. The only thing I can think of would be to throttle requests to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me with template strings.

```
var response = `{"ok":true,"currentPage":1,"noOfPages":119,"otherAlliances":[{"allianceId":2090,"description":"Everyone has a Voice.  Everyone is Equal.  No Wild attacks other than that, treat other members with respect in chat, be active, nothing else but having fun your way!!!","membersCount":"77","name":"Rebels Forever","founderUserId":"18985927","might":"4003992566340","glory":"4439079","ranking":1,"hostUserId":"19002651","host":"Greywolf","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Greywolf","founderName":"GreywolfII","founderGenderAndName":"Lord GreywolfII"},{"allianceId":4428,"description":"When the world isnt what you thought.  Things are not what they seemed.  Phuck it take two of these mix with Alcohol and feel better in the morning.","membersCount":"92","name":"Phuckitol","founderUserId":"450033","might":"3070673000317","glory":"808848","ranking":2,"hostUserId":"450033","host":"Steelman","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Steelman","founderName":"Steelman","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Steelman"},{"allianceId":3253,"description":"Play as you like with the backing of your family. We fight as one and defend as one. Gem prizes will be handed out. Important to have fun and enjoy the game. Zilla","membersCount":"46","name":"Burn In Ashes","founderUserId":"3359434","might":"2596318711111","glory":"1914207","ranking":3,"hostUserId":"12858988","host":"gaz","hostGenderAndName":"Lord gaz","founderName":"Real'Savage","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Real'Savage"},{"allianceId":3262,"description":"Come join us and work as a team to fight and win :)","membersCount":"86","name":"Rise of Legends","founderUserId":"15149877","might":"2379467424780","glory":"2237089","ranking":4,"hostUserId":"15149877","host":"BRETT","hostGenderAndName":"Lord BRETT","founderName":"BRETT","founderGenderAndName":"Lord BRETT"},{"allianceId":3215,"description":":) zero drama tolerance, a place to fight and have fun. Is suppose to be a game after all","membersCount":"67","name":"trouble makers","founderUserId":"1887356","might":"2348999870474","glory":"2428809","ranking":5,"hostUserId":"11564038","host":"Dem0","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Dem0","founderName":"'Echo'","founderGenderAndName":"Lady 'Echo'"},{"allianceId":4924,"description":"","membersCount":"52","name":"WDW","founderUserId":"11577054","might":"2271325408341","glory":"2996503","ranking":6,"hostUserId":"11577054","host":"Nordic","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Nordic","founderName":"Nordic","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Nordic"},{"allianceId":2792,"description":"Name says it all :)","membersCount":"80","name":"Wicked MisFits","founderUserId":"18718109","might":"1984311364223","glory":"2303516","ranking":7,"hostUserId":"18718109","host":"Of_Sin","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Of_Sin","founderName":"Of_Sin","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Of_Sin"},{"allianceId":3881,"description":"","membersCount":"55","name":"LA  MEUTE","founderUserId":"14440588","might":"1807184812409","glory":"862782","ranking":8,"hostUserId":"15336296","host":"lepoison","hostGenderAndName":"Lord lepoison","founderName":"LouvePoison","founderGenderAndName":"Lady LouvePoison"},{"allianceId":3273,"description":"Italians do it better.","membersCount":"80","name":"MADE in ITALY","founderUserId":"18656989","might":"1799034994799","glory":"718309","ranking":9,"hostUserId":"19009341","host":"Super_Bicio","hostGenderAndName":"Lord Super_Bicio","founderName":"Leonida","founderGenderAndName":"Lord Leonida"},{"allianceId":5283,"description":"Fight and have fun!","membersCount":"26","name":"War  Crimes","founderUserId":"15105685","might":"1599775320583","glory":"6732908","ranking":10,"hostUserId":"15105685","host":"Hillz","hostGenderAndName":"Lady Hillz","founderName":"Hillz","founderGenderAndName":"Lady Hillz"}]}`

var data = JSON.parse(response)
console.log(data)
```